# How to make my custom uipickerview show from a montouch dialog StyledStringElement tapped event

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a custom uipickerview with backing uipickerviewmodel.

It works great with text fields but I've found myself creating elaborate custom xibs just to be able to hold a text field so i can set the inputview to my picker so it becomes the firstresponder.

Surely there must be a simpler way I can somehow wire up the tapped event of stylestringelement to show the picker?

Please can someone help with a code snippet of MT.D element opening a picker using tapped, I'm really stuck as I can only so far get an actionsheet with the picker inside but not able to attach a toolbar (inputaccessoryview).